# CF- Tag timeout

Tags: java, coldfusion, timeout, cfml

I have a web application coded in Coldfusion 2016. The ColdFusion is written for the front end but i have a Java backend . For one my pages I process the removal of a user from the application. The page calls the Java backend which does a number of things, via a HTTP request. The HTTP takes awhile, and I get a timeout issue. The problem is, I cant extend the time out, because I have CFX (custom) tags, on the page. I was reading from the [adobe docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-mx-explanation-request-timeout.html) that CFX tags do not listen to the application/page timeout settings. Is there a way to extend the timeout for this request ?

Code example (though idk if its that much help)

```
<cfflush interval = "10">
<cfsetting RequestTimeout = "120">
<cfset appServer = new app.modules.user.userRequest.init(session.user_id)>
...
<cfset variables.response = appServer
.getRequest(
    urlPath = variables.processUrl,
    urlParam = { 'user_id' = session.user_id },
    formParam = variables.requestForm
)>
<cfset variables.results = DeserializeJSON(variables.response)>
...

<h1>
    <cf_displayText title="#session.user_id#" >
</h1>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            ....
```

Comment: (I don't see any CFX tags, only Custom Tags "cf_xxx", but...)  Why not pass a timeout value into the CFX and have it abort the http call if the timeout is exceeded?

Comment: `"The ColdFusion is written for the front end but i have a Java backend ."` Not related to the question, but I don't typically view CF as a front-end language, and it already ties in pretty tightly with Java for the back-end and middle-tier things that it excels at. If you're dealing with problems passing HTTP calls from CF to Java and then timing out while waiting for a return, you might make things easier for yourself (and quicker) by refactoring the front-end to an actual front-end language and using your CF and Java as your middle and back.